# Adding custom code to a WordPress site

Tags: plugins

I have coded a small calculator in 3 files, HTML/JS/CSS + 1 image, and I need to integrate it in the main column of a WordPress site. It's a standard calculator tool, a div with 2 dropdown, and a result appearing when options are selected.

The tool needs to appear just as an article would, taking all the main column of a 3 columns layout. Maybe it could be a shortcode but not a sidebar widget.

I just need this piece of custom code to display in a page. No other requirements. I'm a software coder and have no WP experience.
What's the best way to do that, do I need to make a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

If your custom code should output something where normally you have post content, use a **shortcode**.

Convert your code in a plugin, this can be done simply adding plugins header, even only

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 */
```

on top of your php file. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

After that use the `add_shortcode` function to output your content. [See docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

Remember that the function that handle the shortcode must **return** the output, and not echo it.

After that, an advice regarding style and script. In WordPress, right way to add styles and scripts to frontend are the functions [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) both called inside a function that hooks into [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

If you do this, probably you want to know a way to enqueue scripts/and styles only in posts that contain the shortcode, for that look at [`has_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) function.

Finally, to use both `wp_enqueue_*` functions, and to insert the image you said you have, you need to know the url of your plugin folder.
Please do not hardcode it, but use [`plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) function to correctly retrieve it.

Without seeing your code, there are no much more things I can say, try to implement what I said and if you have problems try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for this useful advice! That's exactly the kind of info I needed.